# Strong extractors with reusable seeds

Tags: cr.crypto-security, randomness, extractors

I have convinced myself of the following:

For every [$(k,\epsilon^2\hspace{.005 in})$-strong extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Strong_extractors) Ext, for every distribution $X$,
if $\;\; k\leq$ [$\:H_{\infty}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy#Min-entropy)$(\hspace{.01 in}X\hspace{.015 in}) \;\;$ then the probability over the seed $U$ that 
the distribution of $\: \text{Ext}\hspace{.01 in}(\hspace{.01 in}X,U\hspace{.015 in}) \:$ is not [$\epsilon$-close](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance) to uniform
is at most $\epsilon$.

> Are there any known
>   [explicit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor#Explicit_extractors)
>   strong extractors that are known to handle seed reuse better than can
>   be shown by using the above on a standard strong extractor?

What if each instance of "extractor" in the rest of this post was replaced with "[blender](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.3.8086)"$\hspace{.01 in}$?